# Uncertain behaviour of Date in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, java-7

I have deployed one project around 2 years before and I have been facing one strange issue in Java.

Following is my line of code that worked for all dates except 29- dec- 2015
In controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/viewTimeSheet")
public ModelAndView viewtimesheet(ModelMap model,@RequestParam(value = "msg", required = false) String msg,@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error) {
    if(SessionManagement.isSessionAlive()!=true)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:../pleaseLogin");
    }
    if (error != null) {
        model.put("error", error);
    }

    if (msg != null) {
        model.put("msg", msg);
    }
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd").format(new Date()));
    model.put("total", timeSheetTempDAO.getCurrentDayHours(SessionManagement.getCurrentUserId(),new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd").format(new Date())));
    model.put("timeSheetTempList",timeSheetTempDAO.getDailyTimeSheets(SessionManagement.getCurrentUserId()));
    return new ModelAndView("viewTimeSheetTempTile");
}
```

In DAO

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<TimeSheetTemp> getDailyTimeSheets(int userId) {
    List<TimeSheetTemp> list = new ArrayList<TimeSheetTemp>();
    Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("FROM TimeSheetTemp t where userId="+userId +" and date='"+new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd").format(new Date())+"' order by id");
    list = (List<TimeSheetTemp>) q.list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    for(TimeSheetTemp t : list){
        if(t.getStatus().getId()!=1){
            if(t.getReviewedBy()!=null && t.getReviewedBy()!=0){
                t.setReviewedByName(getFullName(t.getReviewedBy()));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

[image: java date error]

You can see my date in console is 2016 where as my system date is 2015!!!

Also in my database 2015 year is added. Can someone please explain me why this is happening?

Comment: should be `yyyy-MMM-dd`

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the issue is. Also, don't, ever, use String concatenation to parameterize queries. Use named parameters. And pass a parameter of type Date rather than passing a String, whose format is database, locale and timezone-dependant.

Comment: YYYY is week year, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getWeekYear() . Simply saying for week year the last week of the previous week is part of the next year unless the full week fits into the previous year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Y` in format is for the week-year, not the day-year.

Use `y` instead.

In your case:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind suppot.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is wrong!

Use

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").format(new Date()));
```

instead of

```
 System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd").format(new Date()));
```

"`YYYY`" is week-based calendar year.

"`yyyy`" is ordinary calendar year.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suppot.